# How do I set parameters for margins and justification within a tasks environment?

Tags: tasks

I would like to know how to control three aspects of the `tasks` environment:

- How to eliminate extraneous space before the task counter,
- How to control the space between tasks
- How to set the paragraph formatting universally

In the following example, I would like the task numbers `1` and `5` to be flush with the left margin.  I would also like to add space between the tasks so that, for example, task `5` and `6` are not so close together.  Finally, I would like to set the paragraph formatting within each task to `\raggedright` without having to manually do it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\newcommand\sample{This is a sample sentence that spans more than one line of the final documents.}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{\rule[-4in]{0.4pt}{4in}}%%

\sample \sample \sample
\begin{tasks}[counter-format={\bfseries tsk[1].}](4)
  \task This 
  \task that 
  \task something else
  \task something even more
  \task \sample \sample
  \task \sample more more more
  \task \raggedright\texttt{\detokenize{\raggedright}} set here. \sample
  \task something
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting`column-sep=1em, item-indent=1.3333em`  yields the results you desire:

[image]

The lengths are defined as

[image]

where `item-offset` I think should have been `label-offset`.

### Notes:

- The defaults are `label-width=1em` and `label-offset=0.3333em`. Hence, setting `item-indent=1.3333em` yields the task counter aligned with the margin.
- The default for `column-sep=0pt` hence setting that value will increase the horizontal spacing.
- You can just set `\raggedright` *before* the `\begin{tasks}` and that will be in effect for all the `tasks`.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\newcommand\sample{This is a sample sentence that spans more than one line of the final documents.}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{\rule[-4in]{0.4pt}{4in}}%%

\sample \sample \sample
{\raggedright%
\begin{tasks}[counter-format={\bfseries tsk[1].}, column-sep=1em, item-indent=1.3333em](4)
  \task This 
  \task that 
  \task something else
  \task something even more
  \task \sample \sample
  \task \sample more more more
  \task \raggedright\texttt{\detokenize{\raggedright}} set here. \sample
  \task something
\end{tasks}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Doubly appreciative of the visual since it reminded me that maybe I should update my version of LaTeX.  And now that I've done so, I can see exactly what you pointed out.

Comment: @A.Ellett: Yeah it helps. I really wish the `enumitem` package would include a similar image as well.

Answer (score 2):

here is a solution, with the help of the `etoolbox` package for the last requirement:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[margin=1in, showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry}
\newcommand\sample{This is a sample sentence that spans more than one line of the final documents.}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\AtBeginEnvironment{tasks}{\raggedright}
\settasks{column-sep=1.5em, item-indent=1.3333em}%

\begin{document}

\noindent
\raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{\rule[-4in]{0.4pt}{4in}}%%

\sample \sample \sample
\begin{tasks}[counter-format={\bfseries tsk[1].}](4)
  \task This
  \task that
  \task something else
  \task something even more
  \task \sample \sample
  \task \sample more more more
  \task \raggedright\texttt{\detokenize{\raggedright}} set here. \sample
  \task something
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

[image]