# How do I understand the horizontal spacing of enumitem's enumerate list?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, enumerate, enumitem

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcommand{\currentsection}{3.5}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\currentsection.\arabic*.}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{align=left,widest=a,leftmargin=*}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item ohai
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item ok
  \item hi
  \end{enumerate}
\item ohai
\item ohai
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

The above snippet somehow aligns the second level enumerate list at the left. I read http://tug.org/texinfohtml/latex2e.html#list and http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf, but I still don't understand how it works. Is there a comprehensive document on the horizontal spacing of enumrate list?

Comment: `texdoc enumitem`? Page 5. If you've read that, it would help to know what you don't understand. What output would you expect? Also, please give us a complete, minimal document we can copy-paste-compile to see what you see.

Comment: I asked the question after I read page 5 on enumitem.pdf and fiddled with relevant variables. The model described on page 5 provides an incomplete picture of the horizontal spacing.

Comment: Very like your incomplete code and incomplete question. What, exactly, do you want to know?

Comment: I want to understand how align, leftmargin, itemindent, labelsep, labelwidth, and labelindent affect the horizontal spacing of the enumerate list at the second level and beyond. I can't predict how changing one variable affects the others, yet.

Comment: The left margin is shifted so that the starting point aligns with the start of an item at level 1. `leftmargin` is then measured right from that point. `itemindent` is then measured rightwards again, from the rightmost point of `leftmargin`. `leftmargin` contains `labelindent` and `labelwidth` and part of `labelsep`. `itemindent` includes the rest of `labelsep`.

Comment: Why do I still see some gaps between label and text with \setlist[enumerate,2]{align=left,labelsep=0pt,leftmargin=*}?

Comment: Does the picture at [How do I set parameters for margins and justification within a tasks environment?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210085/4301) answer your question?

Comment: Ah, '(m)' is significantly wider than '(a)', and widest=m sets minimum label width to that of '(m)'. Thus, widest=a,labelsep=0,leftmargin=* removes the gap between label and text. @PeterGrill The picture helped.... I think I now get the picture.

Comment: Try setting `align=right` and you'll see the label shifted to the right of the label width, so the gap disappears. (Pic below.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this help? I've used `leftmargin=!` since `leftmargin=*` calculates things using the label width of the widest item, so `labelwidth` has no effect, for example.

[image: enumerations]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcommand{\currentsection}{3.5}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\currentsection.\arabic*.}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item ohai
  \begin{enumerate}[align=left,widest=a,leftmargin=!]
    \item the leftmost point of the left margin is aligned with the rightmost point of the left margin of the enclosing list
  \end{enumerate}
  \item ohai
  \begin{enumerate}[align=left,widest=a,labelindent=5mm,leftmargin=!]
    \item the leftmost point of the left margin is aligned with the rightmost point of the left margin of the enclosing list
    \item the label begins 5mm to the right of the left margin
  \end{enumerate}
  \item ohai
  \begin{enumerate}[align=left,widest=a,labelindent=5mm,labelwidth=15mm,leftmargin=!]
    \item the leftmost point of the left margin is aligned with the rightmost point of the left margin of the enclosing list
    \item the label begins 5mm to the right of the left margin
    \item 15mm is allowed for the label
  \end{enumerate}
  \item ohai
  \begin{enumerate}[align=left,widest=a,labelwidth=15mm,leftmargin=!]
    \item the leftmost point of the left margin is aligned with the rightmost point of the left margin of the enclosing list
    \item 15mm is allowed for the label
  \end{enumerate}
  \item ohai
  \begin{enumerate}[align=left,widest=a,labelsep=5mm,leftmargin=!]
    \item the leftmost point of the left margin is aligned with the rightmost point of the left margin of the enclosing list
    \item 5mm is left between the rightmost side of the label and the start of the item body
  \end{enumerate}
  \item ohai
  \begin{enumerate}[align=left,widest=a,itemindent=35mm,leftmargin=!]
    \item the indentation of the item body, relative to the left margin is 135mm, so the left margin is now further left than in the other cases
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

If you set

```
\setlist[enumerate,2]{align=left,labelsep=0pt,leftmargin=*}
```

Then the label is aligned left *within the width of the label*. So there will be some space to the right of the label. If you use

```
[align=right,labelsep=0pt,leftmargin=!]
```

then you see the space disappear:

[image: no space]